# create custom hook to override useState() hook and merge object properties (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, so I'm trying to create a custom hook "useObjectState" so I can utilize objects in functional components a little better and to be able to merge object props. Here's what I have so far:

```
  const useObjectState = initialObject => {
    const [obj, setObj] = useState(initialObject);

    const setMergedObj = x => {
      setObj(obj => ({ ...obj, ...x }));
    };

    return [obj, setMergedObj];
  };
```

And now instead of calling the useState() setter function as follows:

```
  setObject(obj => ({...obj, prop1: newValue}))
```

I can call it this way:

```
   setObject({prop1: newValue});
```

and it will merge just fine. The problem I'm having is with batching multiple calls, where if I don't use the custom hook, then these calls will batch into separate calls and execute consecutively:

```
setObject(obj => ({...obj, prop1: oldVal + 1}));
setObject(obj => ({...obj, prop1: oldVal + 1}));
setObject(obj => ({...obj, prop1: oldVal + 1}));
```

But with the custom hook that I wrote that doesn't seem to work and the last call will override the first two:

```
setObject({prop1: oldVal + 1});
setObject({prop1: oldVal + 1});
setObject({prop1: oldVal + 1}); //only this function works, the other 2 are overwritten
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

**SAMPLE CODE** (as someone asked)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const useObjectState = initialObject => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState(initialObject);

  const setMergedObj = x => {
    setObj(obj => ({ ...obj, ...x }));
  };

  return [obj, setMergedObj];
};

function App() {
  let [obj, setObj] = useObjectState({
    num1: 1,
    num2: 10
  });

  let [obj2, setObj2] = useState({
    num1: 1,
    num2: 10
  });

  const increment = x => {
    setObj({ num1: obj.num1 + 1 });
    setObj({ num1: obj.num1 + 1 });
    setObj({ num1: obj.num1 + 1 }); //this will override the other 2

    setObj({ num2: obj.num2 + 10 }); 

    setObj2(obj2 => ({ ...obj2, num1: obj2.num1 + 1 }));
    setObj2(obj2 => ({ ...obj2, num1: obj2.num1 + 1 }));
    setObj2(obj2 => ({ ...obj2, num1: obj2.num1 + 1 })); //these 3 functions will add 3 at a time to obj2.num1

    setObj2(obj2 => ({ ...obj2, num2: obj2.num2 + 10 }));
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    setObj({ num1: obj.num1 - 1 });
    setObj({ num2: obj.num2 - 10 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => increment(1)}>+</button>
      <div>{obj.num1}</div>
      <div>{obj.num2}</div>
      <div>{obj2.num1}</div>
      <div>{obj2.num2}</div>

      <button onClick={() => decrement()}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Why don't you just use useState and update your props with new obj. Each time you set new prop you will recycle,

Comment: Can you add the full code where you call these `setObject` functions? Obviously if you call these functions one after one it won't work like it won't work even with a single `useState` set method. I guess you're trying to create a `setState` like hook, which is not how hooks intent to work.

Comment: @hurricane purely for convenience reasons, I'm simply a bit tired of having to define multiple useState() hooks for each object property or needing to remember to destructure the object every time. So instead of using multiple useState() hooks with related variables I could dump them all into one object and just update its props.

Comment: Why do you define useState for each object property? Just define one object, which contains all props. What is wrong about it? I think it is better to explain your first problem, which is related with that. Could you show us what is your main problem? Because with this custom hook you overuse the useState functionality which will create other problems in your application. I have been developing complex pages with customhooks never tried to do something like that.

Comment: @hurricane I was trying to get rid of the need to destructure the object every time I need to update it with { ...object, prop: val }

Comment: @ChristosLytras - just posted sample code

Comment: @techexpert when using `setObj({ num1: obj.num1 + 1 });`, `obj` is the state global object which of course does not update before you get a state cycle; at `setObj2(obj2 => ({ ...obj2, num1: obj2.num1 + 1 }));` you don't use the state global `obj2`, but the previous state object passed in `setObj2` set state method which it gets updated after each call.

Comment: @ChristosLytras not sure I understand what you mean by "state global" when describing the objects. What would you say be the solution to do what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes, global is not well put, I mean the component scope state. `obj` refers to the function component scope not `setObj` scope, but `obj2` refers to the `setObj2` and not `obj2` defined at the top of the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue I see is that you are passing a reference to the original object:

```js
setObj({num1: obj.num1 + 1});
```

`setObj()`'s argument has no way of referencing the internally updated state, so `obj.num1` will always reference the original value returned by the hook.

You might want to consider allowing your hook to receive a function, the way the original `useState` does, and rewriting your hook like:

```js
const setMergedObj = x => {
  typeof x === "function"
    ? setObj(obj => ({...obj, ...x(obj)}))
    : setObj(obj => ({...obj, ...x}))
  ;
};
```

Then using it like

```js
setObj(obj => ({num1: obj.num1 + 1}));
```

I can see the object-only version still being relevant, if you're updating date from elsewhere, but you'll need the functional version for referencing the existing state.

Comment: This makes sense, I was trying to pass the function call to the custom hook before and couldn't figure out how to make it work. I will try your suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: Yay! Glad to help!